# Is it possible to pass image to tesseract without using filesystem and, if so, how?

Tags: node.js, tesseract

I am currently using [tesseract.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.js), but would like use the [C++ implementation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) via command-line to achieve higher [performance](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/148). Is it possible to pass image to `tesseract` without using filesystem?

```js
const tesseract = require("tesseract.js")

const buffer = Buffer.from(req.body.imgBase64, "base64")
  tesseract
    .recognize(buffer, "eng")
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).send(result.data.text)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to use tesseract without using filesystem.

Comment: Great answer. Updated the question. How? Can you please include an example?

Comment: SO is not replacement for reading doc! Did you bother to read at least 'tesseract --help-extra' ? Or tesseract documentation? Function available in baseapi.h? If you want to use C++ APi this is basis. Then show us your code. We will not do your homework.

Comment: Please don’t be arrogant. I spent at least an hour searching for an answer before asking here. Also, did you notice the `node.js` tag? I am asking in the context of a spawned process. What are you referring to in `tesseract --help-extra`? `stdin` is used to pass a path, not the content of the file unless you know more than I do about this. If so, please submit an answer.